# VB.NET error correction menu

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ide

In VS2008, using C#, if I type a function that doesn't exist into the editor, I get the option to hit Alt-Shift-F10 and create a stub function; however, if I do the same in VB.NET (same IDE) I don't get this facility.

Is this feature something that needs to be switched on per language, or does this facility just not exist in VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not present in VS2008 but was added to the VB.Net IDE in VS 2010.